# RedisConnectionException : .net core connecting to Redis Cache in AWS

Tags: asp.net-core, redis

While connecting to redis cache in AWS I am getting following error. On localhost it works fine.  Can any suggest whats going wrong.

We do have VPC on AWS, can access other resources like VPC but could not connect to Redis cluster.

> .Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the
>   redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable
>   AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PINGat
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(Func`1
>   multiplexerFactory, TextWriter log) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   890at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String
>   configuration, TextWriter log) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   855at
>   TeamSports.Shared.CacheManager.RedisConnectionFactory.<>cDisplayClass1_0.<.ctor>b0()at
>   System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)at
>   System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
>   executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()at
>   TeamSports.Shared.CacheManager.RedisConnectionFactory.Connection()at
>   TeamSports.Shared.CacheManager.CacheManager..ctor(IConfigurationManager
>   configurationManager, IHostingEnvironment environment, ILogger`1
>   logger

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AWS' ElastiCache or redis hosted on your own VM in your VPC?

If redis is self-hosted, make sure that the Redis server itself is bound on the correct address. It may be bound to `127.0.0.1` which will keep other servers from talking to it. It would have to be bound to `0.0.0.0` or the internal, non-loopback address instead.

Also verify that the security group rules between the two servers allow for the redis machine to accept connections on the port redis listening on from your server (port `6379` by default). This is valid if you're using ElastiCache also.

Secondarily, since it's not entirely clear from your question, is your software expecting a redis on localhost that isn't there? You should verify the application is trying to access the correct address.

Comment: Thanks for responding and sorry from my side to not answer this, I was able to resolve it.  My Cache was accessed by Beanstalk, the security rules were not in place that's why this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by configuring security rules. Here are the details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.ElastiCache.html